# If I'm online i want to call an API , else i want to call another API and show the results , in electron.js, reactJS, express, sqlite

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, sqlite, electron

I'm trying to  create a desktop app with reactjs, for backend express and sqlite for local db. i want to access an API if im online, if offline, i want to call the local api which is connected to sqlite. If possible, how to sync the offline db with online db when internet is available?

Im able to send the request to separate api correctly. if offline, im able to send request but im not getting any response , idk what im missing.

reactjs - APP.js

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

function App() {
  const [response, setResponse] = useState('');
  const [isOnline, setIsOnline] = useState(navigator.onLine);

  useEffect(() => {
    // Define a function to fetch data from the backend
    
 // Call the function to fetch data when the component mounts

    window.addEventListener('online', handleOnline);
    window.addEventListener('offline', handleOffline);

    return () => {
      // Clean up event listeners when the component unmounts
      window.removeEventListener('online', handleOnline);
      window.removeEventListener('offline', handleOffline);
    };
  }, []);

  const handleOnline = () => {
    setIsOnline(true);
  };

  const handleOffline = () => {
    setIsOnline(false);
  };

  const fetchDataFromBackend = async () => {

    if(isOnline==false) {
      try {
        const response = await axios.get('http://localhost:4000/api/data');
        setResponse(response.data); // Set the response data in state
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error fetching data:', error);
      }
    }

    else {
      try {
        const response = await axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users');
        setResponse(response.data); // Set the response data in state
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error fetching data:', error);
      }
    }
  
  };


  const fetchData = () => {
    if (window.require) {
      // We are in Electron, so send an IPC message to the main process
      const { ipcRenderer } = window.require('electron');
      ipcRenderer.send('fetch-data');
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>React App</h1>
      <button onClick={fetchDataFromBackend}>Fetch Data from Backend</button>
      {response && <p>Response from Backend: {response[0].email}</p>}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

node, express

```
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const sqlite3 = require('sqlite3');

const app = express();
const port = 4000;

app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());

const db = new sqlite3.Database('database.db');

// Define a route to fetch data from the database
app.get('/api/data', (req, res) => {
  // Example SQL query to select data from a table
  const query = 'SELECT * FROM users'; // Replace with your table name and query

  db.all(query, (err, rows) => {
    if (err) {
      console.error('Error executing SQL query:', err);
      res.status(500).json({ error: 'An error occurred while fetching data.' });
    } else {
      res.json(rows); // Send the fetched data as a JSON response
    }
  });
});

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server is running on port ${port}`);
});
```

electronjs - main.js

```
const { app, BrowserWindow } = require('electron');

function createWindow() {
  // Create the browser window
  mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration: true,
      // Set your CSP policy here to allow content from localhost
      contentSecurityPolicy: "default-src 'self' http://localhost:3000; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval';",
    },
  });

  // Load your React app's HTML file
  mainWindow.loadURL('http://localhost:3000');

  // Open the DevTools in development mode
  if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
    mainWindow.webContents.openDevTools();
  }

  // Listen for the window being closed
  mainWindow.on('closed', () => {
    mainWindow = null;
  });
}

// Create the main window when the app is ready
app.whenReady().then(createWindow);

// ... Rest of your Electron main process code ...
```